# Android Studio and Parse. SOS

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm working in **Android Studio and Parse**.
I wrote a lot of details in the table in Parse, and I pull them into the code . For some reason , he didn't "pulled" all the cases ( there were about 150 ) so I deleted the first 30 that he succeeded pulling into the code,  and I rewrite them again ( just as they were ), but now the software is not working and collapsing in this following sentences :

q.findInBackground(new FindCallback()

sentence = list;//referance to global var

***Here is the full code:***

public void  selectedCharacter(String story)
{

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject>q = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Sentence");
   q.whereEqualTo("story", story);
   q.orderByAscending("rank");
   p=ProgressDialog.show(this,"YOLO","Loading, please wait...",true);
   p.setCancelable(true);
   p.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
   p.setMessage("Loading...");
   p.show();

   q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
   {
       @Override
       public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e)//list means all the line from the parse
       {
           sentence = list;//referance to global var
           String str = list.get(0).getString("desc");
           tv.setText(str);
           String r = sp.getString("rank", "0"); //"0" is default
           count = Integer.valueOf(r);
           if(r!=null)
               Log.d("roni",r);
           else
           {
               Log.d("roni","r is null");

           }

           Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, sentence.get(count).getString("rank"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           String charaSpeak = list.get(0).getString("character");
           charaName.setText(charaSpeak);
           Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, sentence.get(count).getString("mood"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           setImageByMood(sentence.get(count).getString("mood"));
           p.dismiss();

       }
   });}
```

***(Thank you very much in advance)***

Comment: MISTAKE: the software is not working and collapsing in this following sentences :
 String str = list.get(0).getString("desc");
q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()

Comment: Collapse means uncatched excpetion? You should check if(e==null) then do the following things. if(e!=null) you should see what exception it is. BTW, you should check list.size() >0, or it will get indexOutOfBound exception.